# Paperback pulp action hero novel with Vegans?

Tags: story-identification

Back in the 1970s or 1980s I was looking at a paperback book in the science fiction section of a book store.

I don't remember if I noticed whether it was contemporary novel or a reprint from decades earlier.

I think I remember that it was about a pulp action hero who was a bit more than a normal human.  Someone like [Doc Savage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Doc_Savage_novels), the Man of Bronze, for example. Or [Captain Future](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Future#Stories), or someone else.

And maybe it was written by [Earl](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?Earl_Binder) or [Otto Binder](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?Otto_Binder), or both as Eando Binder.

The only thing I remember is a scene with at least one character who was a Vegan from Vega. They said that Vega once ruled a vast space empire, ruling half the galaxy.

There are probably tens or hundreds of science fiction stories involving Vegans of various types.  But I think the detail that Vega once ruled a vast interstellar empire would be much rarer.  The only other example I can think of in fiction from the previous millennium is the Vegan Tyranny from James Blish's *Cities in Flight*.

Added on 01-14/15 2022.  I found a title which could possibly, repeat possibly be the book I remember looking at:  *The Avengers Battle the Earth Wrecker* (1967), by Otto Binder.

I have created an answer with some information about the book.

So that is a possiblility for the book I remember.

Comment: Vegans come from Vega and vegetarians from Vegetaria. Or from Vegeta.

Comment: In *Foundation* (1951), first novel in the *Foundation* series by Isaac Asimov. Vega was the capital of the Vega Province in the Galactic Empire, one of the wealthiest provinces in the entire Galaxy. However, there is no pulp-style hero, unless you count Salvor Hardin, hero of two of the stories.

Answer (score 5):

Could this be *[Agent of Vega](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?52176)* (1949) by James H. Schmitz...?

It was originally published in the [July 1949 edition](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?57518) of *Astounding Science Fiction*, and later republished in *[Agent of Vega & Other Stories](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1553712.Agent_of_Vega_Other_Stories)* in 2001. Here's the summary from Goodreads:

> Previously appearing in separate publications, these stories of the Galaxy are now in a unitary publication. After the Galactic Empire crumbled, the Vegan Confederacy was too weak to survive, yet it prospered because of its secret weapon--telepathy. Not all of the Agents of Vega were human, but all were the most powerful telepaths in the Galaxy.

[The Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent_of_Vega) offers a bit more info:

> Agent of Vega is a science fiction novel by American writer James H. Schmitz, published in 1960. It is a collection of stories that originally appeared separately in magazines. It was republished in 2001 as Agent of Vega & Other Stories.
>
> The tale began in 1949 as a longish short story published in the SF magazine Astounding. In 1960 it appeared as a book, along with three loosely related stories set in the same time and context: "The Illusionists", "The Truth About Cushgar" and "The Second Night of Summer".
>
> In the far future, humans are building a "Confederacy of Vega" to replace the original fallen Empire of Earth. The new empire includes some mutated humans and also some non-humans. Enemies are also a mix of humans and aliens and it is very much space opera, featuring Vega's 'zone agents'. Combat involves both physical weapons and telepathic attacks. It clearly owes a lot to E. E. Smith's Lensman series.
>
> Unlike the six Lensman books, the four stories are only loosely connected. Each features a completely different set of enemies. The non-human telepath Pagadan is the main connecting link, appearing a secondary character in the first story, the main character in "The Illusionists" and makes a brief appearance in "The Truth About Cushgar".
>
> The book is currently available as Agent of Vega & Other Stories. This consists of the original four stories plus "The Custodians", "Gone Fishing", "The Beacon to Elsewhere", "The End of the Line", "Watch the Sky", "Greenface" and "Rogue Psi". None of these are set in the same universe as the Vega tales.

Comment: This is unlikely, since the Confederacy of Vega is at its height during the stories, not fallen from past power.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible answer to my question.

As I said:

> I think I remember that it was about a pulp action hero who was a bit more than a normal human. Someone like Doc Savage, the Man of Bronze, for example. Or Captain Future, or someone else.
>
> And maybe it was written by Earl or Otto Binder, or both as Eando Binder.

And according to Wikipedia, Otto Binder wrote a book with the title of:

*The Avengers Battle the Earth Wrecker*  (1967). The Marvel Comics superhero team The Avengers began in 1963.

https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?213069

https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2822917-the-avengers-battle-the-earth-wrecker

Unless it was a second editon not mentioned in the sources, it would have been a rather old book to be on the shelves when I remember looking at it.  But it could possibly have been the book I remember.